# Countdown timer image changes the audio sound should change in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm displaying reducing countdown timer from 5 to 1 in label. This works properly.

when my timer starts and it displays 5 in the label, it should produce a sound of 5 and when 4 is displayed a sound saying 4 should be played.

I have all `5 sounds from 5 to 1 in my resource file`.

Suggest me how to set this sound when the timer start on that particular label.

Answer (score 2):

// Keep this as an instance variable in your class.

```
NSTimeInterval remainingTime = 5.0;
```

// Scheduling and Firing the timer at every 1 second.

```
NSTimer *timer =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 [timer fire];

-(void) timerFireMethod:(NSTimer *) theTimer {

    remainingTime = remainingTime - 1.0;

    // Set the label with remaining time.
    yourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", remainingTime];

    // Play sound whose file name corresponds to the remaining time value...

    if (remainingTime <= 0.0) {
        [theTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply make your sound name like this 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 .mp3 or what ever extension it is. Now when you writing on label at same time use your text to make sound file name. and play it.

Use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",lbl.text];` after writing text on label.

Comment: i am getting confused on how to play the sound when my timer changes

Comment: By using AVAudioPlayer play the sound, and where you are changing the the text of lebel at the same time and in same method play the sound.

Comment: use this  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:<#(NSTimeInterval)#> target:<#(id)#> selector:<#(SEL)#> userInfo:<#(id)#> repeats:<#(BOOL)#>], pass selector here and update text on label as well as play sound

Comment: i am confused at one point where should i set [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",lbl.text]; on AVAudioPlayer object